# Sf error: Unable to download shapefile in R

Tags: r, r-sp, r-sf

I am trying to plot the map of brazil from a package. here's how I do it

```
install.packages("brazilmaps")
library(brazilmaps)

test <- get_brmap(geo = "State", geo.filter = list(State = 33), class = "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame")

Error: .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'sf', details:
call: get(genname, envir = envir)
error: object 'group_map' not found
```

I cannot understand this error. How do I fix it?

**EDIT** I figured out the issue. I had to reinstall the sf and rgal packages for it to work. There was something funny I did before.

Comment: Did you install `rgdal` and `sf` packages? I had no issues with your code. Plus, which OS are you running R?

Comment: The actual issue I had was to update the R to the latest version 3.5. I was using the older version. For some reason, 'sf' needed the latest version of R to be installed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution here is to upgrade dplyr to something > 0.8.0.

Source: 
https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/969

Comment: I was getting the below error message after loading the sf package, and upgrading dplyr fixed this. Thanks.

> library(sf)
package �sf� was built under R version 3.4.4Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sf’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'sf', details:
  call: get(genname, envir = envir)
  error: object 'group_map' not found